# How do you write two strings to a file in c++

Tags: c++

```
{
    string vertexcharacter = "{";
    string a = "}";



ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("newfile.txt");
myfile << vertexcharacter, a;
myfile.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

the first string is written but the second string does not show up in a text document

Comment: Comma operator strikes again. Turn up your warning level and you'll probably get a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be looking for:

```
myfile << vertexcharacter << a;
```

Currently, you're using the comma operator, so your line is equivalent to:

```
(myfile << vertexcharacter), a;
```

This inserts `vertexcharacter` into `myfile`, discards the result, then evaluates `a` which does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
myfile << vertexcharacter << a;
```

What you currently have

```
myfile << vertexcharacter, a;
```

involves the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which evaluates the first argument (`myfile << vertexcharacter`), discards the result, then evaluates the second argument (`a`). The reason for this is that the comma operator has the lowest precedence.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** `myfile << vertexcharacter << a;`

The comma does something very different than what you expect.  Think of comma kind of like a semicolon.  If you have multiple statements strung together by commas, each statement will be executed in order.  But the last statement is the one whose value is "returned".  For example:

```
int x = 3;
cout << (x+=2, x+5);
```

In this case, `x+=2` executes so that x=5, and then `x+5` is "returned", so the value 10 is inserted into cout.  Your example, on the other hand, is equivalent to

```
(myfile << vertexcharacter), a;
```

Basically, `vertexcharacter` is inserted into `myfile`, and then, if you were capturing the result somehow, like `x = (myfile << vertexcharacter, a);` then you would get x=a.  What you really want is `myfile << vertexcharacter << a;`

Answer (score 0):

It must be

```
myfile << vertexcharacter << a;
```